# Como subir imagens(varias) para o banco de dados Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho um código em `asp.net` que tem por objetivo subir uma imagem pro banco de dados, e preciso adapto-lo de forma a fazer subir várias, só que não tenho ideia de como fazer isso. Segue o código presente:

**Model**

```
    public int ClienteId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Informe o nome do cliente")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe o email do cliente")]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe o endereco do cliente")]
    public string Endereco { get; set; }
    public byte[] Imagem { get; set; }
    public string ImagemTipo { get; set; }
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ClienteId,Nome,Email,Endereco,Imagem,ImagemTipo")] Cliente cliente,HttpPostedFileBase upload)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            if (upload != null && upload.ContentLength > 0) {
                var arqImagem = new Cliente {
                    ImagemTipo=upload.ContentType
                };
                using (var reader = new BinaryReader(upload.InputStream))
                {
                    arqImagem.Imagem = reader.ReadBytes(upload.ContentLength);
                }
                cliente.Imagem = arqImagem.Imagem;
                cliente.ImagemTipo = arqImagem.ImagemTipo;
            }
            db.Clientes.Add(cliente);
            db.SaveChanges();
            TempData["mensagem"] = string.Format("{0} : for incluido com sucesso", cliente.Nome);
            return RedirectToAction("Catalogo");
        }
        return View(cliente);
    }
```

Ao tentar fazer isso modifiquei o campo Imagem no model para:

** public  IEnumerable Imagem { get; set; } **

e o controller assim:

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ClienteId,Nome,Email,Endereco,Imagem,ImagemTipo")] Cliente cliente, HttpPostedFileBase upload)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            if (upload != null && upload.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var arqImagem = new Cliente
                {
                    ImagemTipo = upload.ContentType
                };
                using (var reader = new BinaryReader(upload.InputStream))
                {

                    arqImagem.Imagem = reader.ReadBytes(upload.ContentLength);

                }
                cliente.Imagem = arqImagem.Imagem;
                cliente.ImagemTipo = arqImagem.ImagemTipo;
            }
            db.Clientes.Add(cliente);
            db.SaveChanges();
            TempData["mensagem"] = string.Format("{0} : for incluido com sucesso", cliente.Nome);
            return RedirectToAction("Catalogo");
        }
        return View(cliente);
    }
```

e tenho o seguinte erro :
`Erro   CS0029  Não é possível converter implicitamente tipo "byte[]" em "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<byte[]>"   EnumerableImagem`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ReadBytes retorna byte[]](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.io.binaryreader.readbytes?view=netframework-4.8), por isso na linha de atribuição de `arqImagem.Imagem` da erro quando você altera essa propriedade para `IEnumerable`.

```
public virtual byte[] ReadBytes (int count);
```

Mas há mais problemas na sua solução, sua model representa a tabela no banco de dados. Você não pode apenas alterar a propriedade para um `IEnumerable`. É necessário alterar a estrutura do banco de dados fazendo com que essa `model` cliente se relacione com uma `model` de imagem em um relacionamento `1:N`.

Ficaria assim:

```
public class Cliente
{
    public int ClienteId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Informe o nome do cliente")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe o email do cliente")]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe o endereco do cliente")]
    public string Endereco { get; set; }
    public int ImagemId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Imagem> Imagens { get; set; }
    public string ImagemTipo { get; set; }
}

public class Imagem
{
    public int ImagemId { get; set; }
    public byte[] Imagem { get; set; }
}
```

Lembrando de fazer os mapeamentos necessários utilizando `DataNotations` ou `FluentAPI`.

Note ainda que se o banco estiver em produção você precisará realizar uma migração das imagens para a nova tabela utilizando o `migration` se estiver usando o `Code First`, mas inicialmente esse é o procedimento que deve fazer para ajustar seu BD para o relacionamento de 1 cliente para N imagens.

Comment: Obrigado pelas correções, amigo. Sobre o erro de conversão..... ele da na seguinte linha  '    using (var reader = new BinaryReader(upload.InputStream))
                    {
                        
                        arqImagem.Imagem = reader.ReadBytes(upload.ContentLength);
                       
                    }'  como eu converto isso Trabalhar com IEnumerable? sem dar esse erro?

Comment: @RafaelG, coloquei mais detalhe na resposta.